# How does React track element instances without keys

Tags: reactjs

I was doing some testing around keys and I'm having trouble understanding the results. I made a Counter and App to test with:

```
function Counter(props) {
  const [cnt, setCnt] = React.useState(0);
  setTimeout(() => {setCnt(cnt + 1)}, 1000);
  return (<p>{props.heading}: {cnt}</p>);
}

function App() {
  const [forceupdate, setForceupdate] = React.useState(0);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setForceupdate(forceupdate+1);
  }, 1000);

  return (
    <>
      {Math.random() < 0.7 && <Counter heading="A" />}
      <Counter heading="B" />
    </>
  );
}
```

React knows to always match the counter with label B with itself. For example, this might display `A:3  B:10` and then display `B:11` the next frame after A disappears.

How does it know to do this instead of outputting `B:4` by using A's state? Does JSX generate a key for every JSX element when compiling to React?

For example, the result is different if I use this instead:

```
  if(Math.random() < 0.7) {
    return (
      <>
        <Counter heading="A" />
        <Counter heading="B" />
      </>
    );
  }
  else {
    return (<><Counter heading="B" /></>);
  }
```

Comment: At a super high level, behind the scenes every React component is a function. It's my understanding that state and other effects for a component are simply tied to the scope of that function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<>
  {Math.random() < 0.7 && <Counter heading="A" />}
  <Counter heading="B" />
</>
```

The main way react decides whether to update a component or mount a new one is by comparing types. If the type has changed, then a new instance is mounted. If the type is the same, it keeps the old instance, updating the props if necessary.

Your two examples of code differ in one important way: example 1 always returns two children, while example 2 switches from returning two children to returning one child. Let's walk through the code, assuming it fails the random check on the first render, and passes on the second. On the first render, we return a fragment with 2 children: `false`, and a `Counter` element. The second render returns a fragment with 2 children: a `Counter` and another `Counter`. React needs to reconcile this to see what changed.

- First, react compares the fragments. There are no differences, so it moves on to the fragment's children.
- Next it compares the first children, and sees `false` before, and a `Counter` after. This is a new type, so it mounts a Counter.
- Next it compares the second children, and sees `Counter` before, and `Counter` after. These are the same type, so it keeps the existing instance mounted. If props had changed those would be updated, but there were no changes in this case.

---

Now with the second piece of code. The first render returns a fragment with just 1 child, a `Counter`. There is no `false` in the output. The second render returns a fragment with 2 children, both `Counter`s

- First, react compares the fragments. There are no differences, so it moves on to the fragment's children.
- Next it compares the first children. It sees a `Counter` before and a `Counter` after. These are the same type, so it keeps the existing instance mounted, and updates its props.
- Next it compares the second children. It sees that there was no 2nd child before, and a `Counter` afterwards. As a result it mounts a new `Counter`.

Comment: Oh, so the && trick actually gives a `false`, that was what's confusing me